# getting value in angularjs and quotemark

Tags: angularjs, smarty, addslashes

I have some project written by someone else using AngularJS and i have to do small changes in it.

There are forms, where user can insert their own text, and it is then displayed on page.
But as far, as i can see, it's not save. 
For example, here is fragment of TPL displaying images:

> `<img src="{$category->iconUrl}" alt="{$category->name}" title="{$category->name}">`

Everything works fine, until user will input quote  mark in category name.

is there any way to add something like php "addslashes"? in easy way?

So far we've spend with 3 coworkers 6 hours each on so simple task and we all already hate AngularJS :) But work must be done.

Comment: `{$category->name}` is NOT anuglarJS (looks like Smarty)

Answer (score 0):

It lookes like the category name is inserted in PHP rather than by AngularJS.

If it is Smarty, then the correct syntax would be:

```
<img src="{$category->iconUrl}" alt="{$category->name}" 
     title="{$category->name|escape}">
```

Comment: This looks loke not working correctly.

Now i have:

> `<img src="{$category->iconUrl}" alt="{$category->name|escape}" title="{$category->name|escape}">`

The result is now, that it has modified UTF8 character, but didn't escaped quotation mark

Comment: is your template engine Smarty?

Comment: that's what i through for quite long time, but no, it's angularJS